# Pythonic way to delegate unknown dict to correct dataclasses of many dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Let's say I have the following data classes:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class VisitNotification:
    visit_id: str
    status: str

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ConversationNotification:
    message_id: str
    status: str
```

and i have software pulling messages off of a queue that could be either
`{"visit_id": "foo", "status": "bar"}` or `{"message_id": "foo", "status": "bar"}`

I guess I could do something like this, but it feels messy, so I'm looking for a more pythonic and clean solution to delegate an unknown type of message to the appropriate dataclass

```
try:
    data = VisitNotification(**message)
    return data
except TypeError:
    pass

ConversationNotification(**message)
return data
```

more info

- the incoming data/dataclasses are more complex, so i'd want separate classes
- this program is essentially a queue reader pulling messages off of a queue
- i have no control over the data or how it comes in because it comes from a 3rd party

Comment: Can you control how the messages come in? The ideal solution would be to have a discriminating field, say, "class_type", and then look that field up in a dictionary to figure out the name of the class.

Comment: This feels like a complicated solution in search of a problem - can you provide a more concrete example of where you'd use this? I'm sure there's way better and more Pythonic ways to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Are you looking for both dict objects to map to the same class, or prefer to keep it as a separate class are you currently have it?

Comment: Is the version of python new enough for the data to always be sorted? If so, is the first key always the discriminator? If so, make a dictionary mapping the key name to the dataclass. If no, and probably better even if yes, add a key to discriminate dict types.

Comment: updated with more info

Comment: we are using pydantic drop in dataclasses ...  the runtime checking is important for us  (the dataclasses are more complex than what i've shown). also easier development with typing

Comment: Why this looks messy to you? In Python is [EAFP](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, as you're using `pydantic`, I think this is what you're looking for:

```py
from typing import Union

from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic.tools import parse_obj_as


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class VisitNotification:
    visit_id: str
    status: str


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ConversationNotification:
    message_id: str
    status: str


T1 = Union[VisitNotification, ConversationNotification]


o1 = parse_obj_as(T1, {"visit_id": "foo", "status": "bar"})
assert type(o1) is VisitNotification

o2 = parse_obj_as(T1, {"message_id": "foo", "status": "bar"})
assert type(o2) is ConversationNotification
```

Comment: Can you explain further how this solves the OP's problem?

Comment: It uses `parse_obj_as` which is a helper function that pydantic offers, to load into either of the models. I guess performance wise, it's not great as it should use the same error handling logic as in the post. But to me it seems more pythonic, and I guess that's what the OP was looking for.

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to include those details.